# Why does the Constant Buffer update partially in Direct11

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, directx-11

Working my way through the "Introduction to 3D Game Programming with Directx 11". I am reworking the samples so as to not use the Effects Framework, so far all good.

However, I have come up with a problem that one of the constant buffers only partially updates.

CPU side CB struct:

```
struct CBPerFrame
{
    DirectionalLight  DirLight[3];
    DirectX::XMFLOAT3 EyePositionW;

    DirectX::XMFLOAT4 FogColour;

    float             FogStart;
    float             FogRange;

    int               LightNumber;
    double            Padding;
};
```

Where I update the CB prior to any drawing.

```
CBPerFrame cbPerFrame { };

    cbPerFrame.DirLight[ 0 ] = mDirectionalLights[ 0 ];
    cbPerFrame.DirLight[ 1 ] = mDirectionalLights[ 1 ];
    cbPerFrame.DirLight[ 2 ] = mDirectionalLights[ 2 ];

    cbPerFrame.EyePositionW  = mEyePosW;

    cbPerFrame.FogColour     = XMFLOAT4( Colors::Black );
    cbPerFrame.FogRange      = 1.0F;
    cbPerFrame.FogStart      = 0.0F;

    cbPerFrame.LightNumber   = mLightCount;

    cbPerFrame.Padding       = 0.0;

mD3DImmediateContext->UpdateSubresource( mCBPerFrame.Get( ), 0, nullptr, &cbPerFrame, 0, 0 );
```

Pixel Shader:

```
cbuffer CBPerFrame : register( b0 )
{
    DirectionalLight gDirectionalLights[ 3 ];
    float3           gEyePosW;

    float4           gFogColor;
    float            gFogStart;
    float            gFogRange;

    int              gLightCount;
    double           gPadding;
}

cbuffer CBPerObject : register( b1 )
{
    matrix   gWorld;
    matrix   gWorldInverseTranspose;
    matrix   gWorldViewProjection;
    float4x4 gTextureTransform;
    Material gMaterial;
}

float4 main( VertexOut input ) : SV_TARGET
{
    // Interpolating normal can unnormalize it, so normalize it.
    input.NormalW = normalize( input.NormalW );

    // The toEye vector is used in lighting.
    float3 toEye = normalize( gEyePosW - input.PositionW );

    // Cache the distance to the eye from this surface point.
    float distToEye = length( toEye );

    // Normalize.
    toEye /= distToEye;

    //
    // Lighting.
    //

    // Start with a sum of zero. 
    float4 ambient = float4( 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F );
    float4 diffuse = float4( 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F );
    float4 spec    = float4( 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F );

    // Sum the light contribution from each light source.  
   /* [unroll]*/
    for ( int i = 0; i < gLightCount; i++ )
    {
        float4 A, D, S;

        ComputeDirectionalLight( gMaterial, gDirectionalLights[ i ], input.NormalW, toEye, A, D, S );

        ambient += A;
        diffuse += D;
        spec    += S;
    }

    float4 litColour = ambient + diffuse + spec;

    // Common to take alpha from diffuse material.
    litColour.a = gMaterial.Diffuse.a;

    return litColour;
}
```

gLightCount is always set to 0, even though it should be set to 2 at the start of the application. If I change the condition of the loop to a hardcoded 1/2/3 the shader works as it should.

I realise that there are extra variables in the CB, but the sample code has this and I believe it is used in further examples.

I think the issue is to do with how the CBPerFrame struct is padded, so it isn't been copied over to the GPU correctly. Any thoughts?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with packing. According to [Packing Rules for Constant Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509632(v=vs.85).aspx) data should be packed at 4-byte boundaries but also so data blocks won't cross 16-byte boundary. In this case there will be definitely a padding after `EyePositionW`:

```
struct CBPerFrame
{
    DirectionalLight  DirLight[3];
    DirectX::XMFLOAT3 EyePositionW;
    float             padding1;
    DirectX::XMFLOAT4 FogColour;
```

Also i'm not sure why is there `double gPadding;` at the end. It should probably be another `int`.

Comment: Thank-you I was aware that the CB struct had to be a multiple of 16 bytes, but not that it needed to be aligned on those 16-byte boundaries.